# Wand - Right aligning text with offset

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagemagick, wand

Gravity seemed like what I wanted but it does not let me change the x offset.

```
bg.caption(f"{xp} / {req_xp}", left=200, top=165, font=montserrat_bold, gravity='north_east')
```

Correctly offsets in the y direction but no matter what I put for `left` it remains glued to the right. Is this a bug with wand? I saw several examples of pure imagemagick where alignment seemed possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Captions are created by building a new bounding box (`width x height`), and renders the text to fit within the box -- while respecting the `gravity` parameter. After the text has been rendered, the bonding box is composited at the `left x top` coordinates of the image.

> [...] it remains glued to the right. Is this a bug with wand?

With gravity set to `"north_east"` & `width` undefined, the text will remain "glued to the right".

Try the following ...

```py
bg.caption(f"{xp} / {req_xp}",
           left=200,
           top=165,
           width=100,
           height=50,
           font=montserrat_bold,
           gravity='north_east')
```

Adjust the `width=` & `height=` parameter values to respect the pointsize of `montserrat_bold` variable.

Comment: Thank you! I should have known better than to not experiment with those kwargs.